# Function returning an array in ObjC for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, sdk

Hello
I am trying to make this function to return an array! What is going wrong here?

```
-(char[10])print01:(int)int11{ //error: declared as method returning an array
    char arrayT[10];

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if ((int1-n1)>=0){
            arrayT[i]='1';
            int1-=n1;
        }
        else 
            arrayT[i]= '0';
        n1=n1/2;
    }

    return arrayT[]; // incompatible types in return
}
```

and I want to call it like that:

```
char array1[10] = [self print01:(int)int1]; //error: invalid initializer
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is using an NSArray (of objects of course, I'm assuming the above code is simplified sample, but you can always use an NSNumber).  Alternatively, you could return a pointer to an array, which is common in C as C (and objective c by extension) cannot return an array. Unfortunately, this would require allocating memory for the array and using manual memory management, (malloc/free) which depending on the lifecycle of the array, can be anywhere from a nuisance to awful.  My recommendation is taking a char *dest parameter, and inserting chars into the array as dest[i]

Comment: So you suggest me to read integers instead of chars? Actually I want to have 4 arrays of 8 elements.

Comment: my bad, I was typing that on the iPhone and forgot -- I've changed it to say chars

Answer (score 5):

You can't return an array in C or in Objective-C.  The best you can hope for is to return a pointer to an array, but if you're going to do that, make sure you don't return a pointer to an array on the stack (like yours is).